# How do I upgrade pandas using Anaconda?

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda

I'm using Python 2.7 with pandas version 0.14.1 which I installed with Anaconda and the book I'm reading instructed me to upgrade my pandas version to 0.16.0 (which is supported by Python 2.7) by typing:

```
conda install pandas=0.16.0
```

When I type this command in the Anaconda prompt a series of packages pop up:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
chardet:                3.0.4-py27_1003
conda-package-handling: 1.6.0-py27h3cc03e0_0
pysocks:                1.7.1-py27_0
tqdm:                   4.47.0-py_0
urllib3:                1.25.7-py27_0
win_inet_pton:          1.1.0-py27_0
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
certifi:                2016.2.28-py27_0                --> 2019.11.28-py27_0
conda:                  4.3.30-py27he817781_0           --> 4.8.3-py27_0
conda-env:              2.6.0-0                         --> 2.6.0-1
futures:                2.1.6-py27_0          <unknown> --> 3.3.0-py27_0
menuinst:               1.4.7-py27_0                    --> 1.4.16-py27h0c8e037_1
pandas:                 0.14.1-np19py27_0     <unknown> --> 0.16.0-np19py27_1
pycosat:                0.6.1-py27_0          <unknown> --> 0.6.3-py27h0c8e037_0
requests:               2.14.2-py27_0                   --> 2.24.0-py_0
```

Why is pandas 0.16.0 unknown? Once I type 'y' to install/upgrage these packages, an error occurs and pandas isn't upgraded.

`InsecurePlatformWarning pandas-0.16.0- 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00   5.96 MB/s ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.47.0-py_0'.  CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\Scripts\conda.exe`

What does this error mean and how can I fix it? Also is there any other way to upgrade pandas through Anaconda?

Comment: "I'm using Python 2.7" Stop right there. Don't use Python 2.7, it is officially passed it's end of life. If you are learning Python, you really should be learning Python 3, IOW Python 3 **is** Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.7 is unsupported now.

> The Python core team plans to stop supporting Python 2.7 on January 1st, 2020. In line with NumPy's plans, all pandas releases through December 31, 2018 will support Python 2. The final release before December 31, 2018 will be the last release to support Python 2.

Maybe that’s why a higher version of pandas is not recognised. You can try -

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
#or
conda upgrade pandas
```

Unless it’s absolutely necessary I would recommend uninstalling your version of anaconda and reinstalling anaconda3.

Comment: the book's examples that I'm using only work with Python 2.7 so I can't upgrade my Python version. Also, pandas 0.16.0 is supported by Python 2.7 so I think the upgrade should still work. I've also tried `conda upgrade pandas` but it upgrades to the latest version of pandas and the same error shows up. Do you know if I can fix the error?

Comment: I highly doubt that, pandas in python3 is not that different from that of python2.7. There are minor syntax changes and a lot of new useful functions added but it’s still the same at its core. I would highly recommend that if you are reading a book to upgrade your knowledge, focus your time on the supported versions of python and the latest stable build of pandas.

Comment: Reading code related material for 2.7 will actually do you more harm than good. If you still wanna follow the book then I would recommend try running the code with python3 and making minor syntax changes as and when the code fails.

Comment: Take it from someone who has spend over 8 years on python programming, you don’t wanna touch python 2.7 or anything to do with it unless there is some very very very specific legacy dependency that you just have to work with as part of your work ( it would be better to re write that in python 3 yourself as well)